# python equivalent to perl's LWP and HTTP::Parse

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I need to know if there is and equivalent to perl's LWP and HTTP::Parse. I've a perl script to get the content from an URL and parsing it and I would like to port it to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Python modules httplib and urllib for the fetching part. There are a couple xml modules in Python for parsing. You could also look at BeautifulSoup which is not part of standard Python modules.

Comment: Following your answer I've also found HTMLParser (http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html?highlight=html%20parsing) module.
Thanks for your help.